# How to set multiple classes in my case?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, class

I am trying to setup multiple conditions in my ng-class in my app. I have something like

```
 <div id='wrapper' ng-class="{red: !isBlue(), 
                              highlight ? 'yellow' : 'black'}" 
 ng-show="test">Test</div>
```

JS

```
  $scope.highlight = false;
```

My problem is that I got syntax error on the ng-class condition.

```
Syntax Error: Token ';' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 48...
```

I am not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use multiple classes like this, you need to add separate classes for `highlight` and `!highlight`

```
<div id='wrapper' 
                ng-class="{'red': !isBlue(), 'yellow':highlight ,'black':!highlight }"
                ng-show="test">
       Test
</div>
```

here is a Demo [Plunker  (ng-class)](http://plnkr.co/edit/FickeafjmxRED8EYzBCp?p=preview)

---

you have another alternative `ng-style` with this you can achieve something like u tried,

```
<div id='wrapper' ng-style="{color: (highlight ? 'yellow' : 'green')}" ng-show="test">Test</div>
```

here is the Demo [Plunker (ng-style)](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9LKw95xhSbRCsGcFdHV?p=preview)